# C++ pointer confusion (Binary Search Tree)

Tags: c++

```
struct node{
  int element;
  node* left;
  node* right;
};

typedef node* SET;

void INSERT(int x, SET* A){
  node* pA = *A;
  if (pA == NULL){
    pA = new node;
    pA->element = x;
    pA->left = NULL;
    pA->right = NULL;
  }
  else{
    if (x < pA->element){
      INSERT(x,&(pA->left));
    }
    else if (x>pA->element){
      INSERT(x, &(pA->right));
    }
  }
}

int main(){
  node* A = NULL;
  INSERT(1,&A);
  cout <<A->element<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The Code above is a simple insertion method that will insert an element into the BST. I just keep getting segment default when I access A->element. Many Thanks from your answer.

**Edit:**

wow, this pointer stuff is really confusing. So when I do node* pA = *A, I thought I would create a pointer pointing to the location of A. Then when I do pA = new node, it would create a node object in the heap pointing by pA which is the same as A. Am I saying anything wrong?

Comment: You're missing `*A = pA` after `new`.

Comment: why node* A = NULL; ? why not node* A = new node; ?

Comment: Consider reading about _C++ references_.  Aside from the `cout` line, this code is C.  And C++ added references to avoid confusing pointers-to-pointers-to-things scenarios like the one that's biting you now.

Comment: In this case I think the typedef actually makes the code more confusing. If you just said `node*` and `node**` you would at least know how many levels of indirection you had.

Comment: @Drew Dormann Yea, you are right. I used to program in Java, then move to C, and now need to move back to C++. So I am pretty much confused the code has more than two *'s. I will read about the C++ reference that you mentioned about. But is it a book?

Comment: @tuğrul büyükışık, if you look at the code, I need to test for NULL tree, which is essentially indicated by NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using C++ references.

References allow the `A` in `INSERT` and the `A` in `main` to represent the same data, reducing pointer confusion.

```
struct node{
  int element;
  node* left;
  node* right;
};

void INSERT(int x, node* &A){
  if (A == NULL){
    A = new node;
    A->element = x;
    A->left = NULL;
    A->right = NULL;
  }
  else{
    if (x < A->element){
      INSERT(x,&(A->left));
    }
    else if (x>A->element){
      INSERT(x, &(A->right));
    }
  }
}

int main(){
  node* A = NULL;
  INSERT(1,A);
  cout <<A->element<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't changing `*A`:

```
 if (pA == NULL) {
     pA = new node;
     pA->element = x;
     pA->left = NULL;
     pA->right = NULL;

     *A = pA;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change it to:

```
void INSERT(int x, SET* A){
  if (*A == NULL){
     *A = new node;
     *A->element = x;
     *A->left = NULL;
     *A->right = NULL;
 }
 /* The rest */
```

Comment: You're missing one layer of indirection. `SET*` is a `node **`.